# JS Form validation (Regex, or anything)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script here that is supposed to run when triggered. However, it will only work if the variable passwd is not used in my if else statements. 
**NEWLY UPDATED JS:**

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var add = document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
    var passwd = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
    var matchesCount = email.split("@").length - 1;
    var matchesCount2 = email.split(".").length - 1;
    var error = "";
    if (!name || !phone || !email || !add || !passwd) {
        error+="All must be filled out \n"

        if(phone.search(/^[0-9]*$/) == -1  || phone.length != 8){
            error+="- Phone number can only contain digits \n";}

        if(passwd.search(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/) == -1){
            error+="- Password needs to be alphanumeric \n";
        }

        if(passwd.length <8 || passwd.length > 16){
            error+="- Password contain only 8-16 digits \n";
        }

        if(matchesCount > 1 || matchesCount2 < 1){
            error+="- Please enter a valid email \n";
        }
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="newaccount">
        <table id="tablenewuser">
                <form name="myForm" action="ControllerServlet" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd">Name:<span class="price">*</span></td>
                        <td class="newusertd"><input style="color: black;" type="text" name="name" class="Btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd">Contact Number:<span class="price">*</span></td>
                        <td class="newusertd"><input style="color: black;" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="98989898"class="Btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd">Email:<span class="price">*<br></span></td>
                        <td class="newusertd"><input style="color: black;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="xxx@hello.com" class="Btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd">Address:<span class="price">*</span></td>
                        <td class="newusertd"><input style="color: black;" type="text" name="address" class="Btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd">Password:<span class="price">*</span><br>(8-16 Characters with<br>one UPPERCASE & numbers)</td>
                        <td class="newusertd"><input style="color: black;" type="password" name="password" class="Btn">
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="newusertd"></td>
                        <td class="newusertd">
                            <input style="color: black;" type="submit" value="Create Account" class="Btn"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </form> 
        </table>
    </div>
```

(Sorry for the mess!)

EDIT: The script works but the the password is not working as it should be. Please see the comments

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error? Can you post your HTML or a jsfiddle?

Comment: The javascript does not show the alert when supposed to. Please check the update

Answer (score 0):

Quick glance shows at least 2 problems with that area:

- `passwd` could be `null` and pass through the outer `if` condition.  Attempting `length` on it would cause an error

  You may want to wrap the inner conditionals in an `else` block

  ```
  if (name == null || name == "" || phone == null || phone == "" || email == null || email == "" || add == null || add == ""
          || passwd == null || passwd == "") {
    error+="All must be filled out \n";
  } else {
    // other conditions
  }
  if (error) alert(error);
  ```
- In JS, it's `passwd.length` not `length()`

You should use the JS console to verify what errors are appearing.

Comment: May i know where is the JS console? Also, I tried to change to .length, it did not seem to work since i tested it on my variable phone

Comment: Depending on your browser and OS, there's different ways to access it.  F12 is a common shortcut to bring it up, but otherwise try doing a web search for your particular setup.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, `.length` is a property, not a method. Your length check should be:

```
if (passwd.length >= 8 && passwd.length <= 16) {
     error += "- Only 8-16 digits \n";
}
```

One more note, `foo == null || foo == ""` can be simplified to `!foo` as `null` and `""` are both falsy values in JS.

Comment: It seems that that isn't the only problem. Im not sure if my regex or logic is wrong

Comment: If i entered '77778888' which is exactly 8 digits, the alert shows that phone numbers need to be only in digits. if i were to not type in the password, both error mesages of `error+="- Password needs to be alphanumeric \n";` and `error+="- Only 8-16 digits \n";` should appear. These are the problems found

Comment: I see you were using `.length()` there as well, I missed that the first time. Also, you don't need to quote your regex patterns: https://jsfiddle.net/sa0rcymm/1/

Comment: This new fiddle does fix the phone number issue :) However, if i were to leave everything blank, not all of the errors are shown in the alert

Comment: That's because `passwd.search(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/)` doesn't match any invalid characters to show the "invalid characters" message and `if(passwd.length >=8 && passwd.length <=16){` requires the length to be between 8 and 16

Comment: That is a good explaination. Correct me if im wrong: is the logic wrong for this part `if(passwd.length >=8 && passwd.length <=16)` since i only want the error message if the password length is not between 8-16(inclusive of 8 and 16)

Comment: Nope, the logic there looks good if you want 8-16 character length (inclusive) passwords

Comment: I see. Umm when i tried puting 'lala' in the password, it did not show up in the error message?

Comment: OH derp, yeah, the logic for that is backwards: should be `passwd.length < 8 || passwd.length > 16` to check if the supplied passwords is out of bounds

Comment: I think ` if(passwd.search(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/) == -1){
            error+="- Password needs to be alphanumeric \n";
        }` is not working as i tried 'Tommy' but no error on that appear.

Answer (score 0):

Im not expert but i recommend you evaluate mail field with regex (`/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/`) and i created a separated function for validate each of the values in the form for add a text error, then another validation who evaluate if all the fiels pass the evaluation, like yours but i made it liek that: `if(validateName(nameVar) && validateEmail(emailVar)` this is all the code that i made, that validate a correct form mail, a name with alphabetical form and phone without null value:

```
function validateName(nameVar) {
  var nameReg = /^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$/;
  return nameReg.test(nameVar);
}
function validateEmail(emailVar) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test(emailVar);
}

function email() {
    var nameVar = $('#name').val();
    var emailVar = $('#email').val();
    var phoneVar = $('#phone').val();
    var messageVar = $('#message').val();
    if(!validateName(nameVar) ) {
        console.log("dentro");
        $('#nameError').text("Por favor ingresa un nombre valido");
    }else{
        $('#nameError').text("");

    }
    if(!validateEmail(emailVar) || emailVar == "") {
        $('#emailError').text("Por favor ingresa un correo valido");
    }else{
        $('#emailError').text("");
    }
    if(phoneVar == "") {
        $('#phoneError').text("Por favor ingresa un número telefonico");
    }else{
        $('#phoneError').text("");
    }
    if(validateName(nameVar) && validateEmail(emailVar) && emailVar != "" && phoneVar != ""){
            var data = {};
            data.name = nameVar;
            data.email = emailVar;
            data.phone = phoneVar;
            data.message = messageVar;
            //here your validate code with array of values ready for doing something
    }
};
```

and this is the html code:

```
<h4 class="title-yellow contacto" id="title-yellow">Envianos un mensaje</h4>
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" type="text" required >
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required >
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono" type="tel" required >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" rows="4">
                                    </textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">

                                            <button class="email nohover pull-right" id="mail" onclick="email()">ENVIAR</button>
                                            <p id="demo"></p>
                                            <div id="nameError"></div>
                                            <div id="emailError"></div>
                                            <div id="phoneError"></div>
                                            <div id="ajaxMessage"></div>       
                                        </div>




                                    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i would like a solution that is in **a** function.